# Testing Google Pay via Stripe in cypress

Tags: stripe-payments, cypress, google-pay

I'm trying to write a Cypress test that interacts with react-stripe-js's PaymentRequestButtonElement component. Unfortunately I'm hitting a little bit of a stumbling block actually getting my test to render the button (works fine when I manually test).

I've tried mocking the window's `PaymentRequest` function:

```
          cy.window().then(win => {
            if (win.PaymentRequest) {
              // If we’re running in headed mode
              cy.stub(win, 'PaymentRequest').callsFake(getMockPaymentRequest(validPaymentRequestResponse));
            } else {
              // else headless
              win.PaymentRequest = getMockPaymentRequest(validPaymentRequestResponse)
            }
          });
```

but no luck, our button still doesn't appear. I suspect it has something to do with the following error I see in my console:
`Unable to download payment manifest "https://google.com/pay".`, but had a look through Google and seemingly nobody seems to have mentioned this.

I've also tried stubbing `window.Stripe` in a similar way (to mock out the `stripe.paymentRequest` function) but equally no luck there.

Has anyone had any success implementing something similar?

Comment: _Unable to download payment manifest "https://google.com/pay"_ is just some noise. It isn't the root cause. I haven't used cypress before so can't really help here.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test Stripe's Payment Request button in Cypress you will likely need to [mock the Payment Request API](https://simonsmith.io/mocking-stripe-js-methods-with-cypress):

> Now that all the pieces are in place we can attempt to test something a bit trickier, the Payment Request API that Stripe conveniently wraps for us.
>
> This API is used to detect whether a browser supports payment methods like Apple or Google Pay and then handles accepting payments via these APIs.